# How do I get the program to fill in a text field, and make sure that the user is not able to edit what the program has filled in?

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield

I'm using Swift 3 to make an app. On the register screen I want the user to type in their first and last name and then a random alphanumeric string will be generated. This string should automatically be filled in to the username text field, and the user should not be able to change it.

I already have the code for an alphanumeric string:

```
func randomString(length:Int) -> String {
    let charSet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    var c = charSet.characters.map { String($0) }
    var s:String = ""
    for _ in (1...length) {
        s.append(c[Int(arc4random()) % c.count])
    }
    return s
}
```

I just want this string to be filled in automatically by the program itself, and the user should not be able to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first set your string to your texitField

```
textField.text = randmString(length: 10)
```

Then, disable editing of it

```
textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```